# Make A Panel Visible C# Winforms - Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, combobox, panels, c#

What I want is that whenever I choose a certain index in my ComboBox a certain panel will become visible.

So Here is What I've done:

I've created a ComboBox
I've created 2 Panels

I've set the visibility of the 2 Panels in their properties tab to FALSE

However I was not able to set them to visible when somebody selects something on my ComboBox.

```
 private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox3.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            panel9.Visible();

        }
    }
```

*Note*: I've docked the 2 Panels in the same GroupBox.

What's wrong with my code T_T. It says non vocable member. :((

EDIT**** I have a new problem. Everytime I pick another option. The panel which has been set to visible won't get back to hidden.

It will appear when I choose Index 1 but when I choose Index 2 it will also appear o.O?

Answer (score 2):

It says non invocable member as you are calling visible, which is a property, as a method when you place the () after it. Just set the property to a value as below

`panel9.Visible = true;`

Answer (score 1):

It should be `panel9.Visible = true;`

In that case just do something like this

```
if(index == 1)
  {
      panel9.Visible = true;
      panel10.visible = false;
  }
else
{
      panel9.Visible = false;
      panel10.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Whoah!! Thank You! Thank You! Mister :))

Comment: `var visibile = (index == 1); panel9.Visible = visible; panel10.visible = !visible;`  a more semantic name for `visible` might be better.